# lt spice simulations including mosfet

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice

to lt spice users, how do you include a MOSFET into your ltspice circuit? if it helps the mosfet I'm trying to include is IRLZ44N

Comment: The model is [here](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz44n.spi?fileId=5546d462533600a40153573f68cb3e76). It's a .SUBCKT card, so you will need to either select a pre-defined "X" type symbol with 3 terminals or else modify an existing 3-terminal MOSFET symbol to become an "X" type.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to jonk's comment.

1. Download the spi model from the same [link](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz44n.spi?fileId=5546d462533600a40153573f68cb3e76)
2. Include the file in the simulation through `.inc C:/Users/.../Downloads/irlz44n.spi`
3. Rename the mosfet to match the model name.

If you don't want to use this `.inc` command, you can copy the simulation file to the install folder of your LTSpice.

[image: image_1]

Comment: This answer should include how to create a symbol with prefix "x" as mentioned by jonk.
From your schematic, it gives the impression you can just rename the "value" of an existing MOSFET and it will work. But it doesn't.

Comment: Please, review that.  The .spi file does not work with LTSpice VII (17.0.35.).  It throws a "cannot find definition of model for irlz44n" error.  Maybe it worked for you because you used IRFZ44N (note the "F" in lieu of "L") in your schematic and you never actually used the provided .spi file. IRFZ44N comes with LTSpice.

Comment: @gstorto To change the part ID (not its name in the schematic) , just right-click on it in the schematic.  For example, if you placed a BC548, you can change it to, say, TIP31 by right-clicking on the "BC548" text in the schematic.  This will bring the edit dialog so you can enter "TIP31".